# Rotate MATLAB legend

Tags: matlab, rotation

Is there a way to rotate the MATLAB legend inside a plot? The image below should clarify my requirement.
[image: LegendRotation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to play around with the positioning, and need to do more work if you have more than one line plotted, but the following does it for your example.

```
plot(1:10);  % create a dummy line
ha = legend('Plot'); %create a legend
set(ha,'Units','pixels'); % set axes unit to pixels
pos = get(ha,'Position'); % get the axes position
set(ha,'Position',[pos(1) pos(2)-pos(3) pos(4) pos(3)]); % Set the new position
hc = get(ha,'Children'); % Get the legend contents
set(hc(3),'Position',[0.5 0.6 0],'Rotation',90); % Relocate and rotate text
set(hc(2),'Xdata',[0.5 0.5],'YData',[0.1 0.5]); % rotate the line
set(hc(1),'XData',0.5,'YData',0.3); % Rotate the Marker
```

Comment: Can you verify this code in newer MATLAB versions? I'm receiving "Index exceeds array bounds." in 7th line (R2018a)

Answer (score 2):

the legend function can return serval of args:

```
[leg,labelhandles,outH,outM] = legend(varargin)
```

When you ask for the 2nd argument you get a list of all the Children and then you can use what phil's answer:

```
set(hc(3),'Position',[0.5 0.6 0],'Rotation',90); % Relocate and rotate text
set(hc(2),'Xdata',[0.5 0.5],'YData',[0.1 0.5]); % rotate the line
set(hc(1),'XData',0.5,'YData',0.3); % R
```

This is correct for matlab 2021b

Answer (score 1):

The example is not fully automated but should set you on the right route. You need to rotate the box containing the legend, and the label with the text./

```
% Example plot
plot(1:10)
h = legend('something')

% Rotate legend
set(h,'CameraUpVector', [1 0 0], 'Units','pixels','position',[460 230 25 150])

% Rotate text label
txt = findobj(h,'type','text');
set(txt,'rotation',90)
```

Unfortunately, the save as function restores the `'CameraUpVector'`.

Comment: Adjusting the position using absolute pixel values works in a simple scenario but gives unexpected results in complicated subplot figures.

Comment: I agree, and it was part of my initial disclaimer.

Comment: Error on R2018a: *"There is no CameraUpVector property on the
Legend class."*