# How could I rotate in 90 degrees the legend of a plot on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, rotation, matlab-figure, legend, legend-properties

I'm creating some plots and I need to rotate in 90 degrees the legend to avoid the overlapping of the legend over the graphic.

I've tried to use the 'Rotation' propriety but I receive the following message:

> "The name 'Rotation' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'legend'."

Bellow the piece of code that I have used:

```
x = [-pi:0.001:10.*pi];
y=cos(x);

figure
plot(x,y,'Displayname','y = cos(x)')
lgd = legend('show')

set(lgd,'FontSize',5,'Rotation',90)
```

Comment: I don’t know if this is possible or not. But you can put the legend outside the axes, and you can also make multiple columns in you legend to change its size.

Comment: This is a great question, I just spent about 1/2 hour trying to figure this out without luck. Try asking on the [Mathworks page](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/index)

Comment: If you are using matlab R2014a or earlier you can use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377133/5489190) method. However in newer versions `Children` would give you `0x0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array`. I have no idea how to get handle to text, line, and marker in new interface to rotate it manually. Maybe someone more familiar with this topic can solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate MATLAB legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376576/rotate-matlab-legend)

Comment: Hi guys, I've tried this method and doesn't work.